# Acceder a una base de datos preelaborada que no va a modificar el usuario usando SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-sqlite

Tengo una aplicación que pretende leer datos de una base de datos preelaborada que el usuario no va a modificar.

Siguiendo la parte final de [este tutorial](https://www.desarrollolibre.net/blog/android/como-emplear-una-base-de-datos-externa-sqlite-en-android), he guardado en /assets/databases una base de datos.

He creado una clase Database en mi proyecto Android idéntica a la que dice el tutorial.

**Database.java**

```
package com.geology_quiz_and_guides.mineralogy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MINERALOGY";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public Database(Context context, String name,
                        SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

El tutorial añade solo: "Con esto tenemos lista la conexión a nuestra base de datos y podemos realizar las consultas sobre la misma como si fuera una base de datos integrada de manera nativa por Android."

He probado a hacer:

```
`SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MINERALOGY", MODE_PRIVATE, null);;`
```

Y me da error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'openOrCreateDatabase' in 'HomeFragment'
```

No sé si he de cargar de algún modo la clase Database en MainActivity o por qué el error.

Comment: A ver... no sé qué otros errores puede tener pero voy a lo obvio y claro, en el constructor de la clase `Database` le pusiste 4 parámetros -> `public Database(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)`, y tan solo la estás llamando con uno -> `new Database(getActivity());`. Necesitas pasarle **TODOS** los parámetros que le indicas... Es algo muy básico en la programación en java, te recomiendo repasar la teoría básica un poquito! De hecho el propio error te lo indica, el método con los parámetros que te indica no es aplicable a tu llamada con uno.

Comment: @Benito-B Ah ok gracias. Entonces la pregunta es muy tonta. Entonces le hago `db = new Database(getActivity(),"MINERALOGY",null,1);` Pero entonces no sé por qué el tutorial me genera en la clase Database un Databse_Name y una Database_Version. Luego es que si actualizo la version de la db en mi apliación publicada pensaba según leí hacerlo con `setForcedUpgrade` que borra la db antigua de la memoria interna. Es por dejarlo aclarado en una respuesta y dejar la pregunta por si sirve de algo para gente de habla hispana buscando hacer lo mismo

Comment: El tutorial está un poco mal construido, la verdad. Tal como dices, él mismo declara las variables nombre y version en la propia clase... sin embargo luego si te fijas en la clase `Pedido`, la instancia así: `ListSQLiteHelper taskSQL = new ListSQLiteHelper(context, TABLE_NAME, NULL, 1);`. No tiene ningún sentido puesto que esos valores no van a pasarse al `super()` en realidad... pero bueno. El problema de los tutoriales y guías en español es que no suelen ser de la mejor calidad por desgracia

Comment: @Benito-B Yo solo he seguido la parte final del tutorial, que en principio es para el caso más sencillo de tener la base de datos preelaborada (y la mía no se va a modificar por el usuario). El autor dice base de datos externa por eso usé desde mi ignorancia esa terminología. Solo dice de guardar la base de datos en /assets/databases, de crear la clase tal y como la he posteado y luego añade "Con esto tenemos lista la conexión a nuestra base de datos y podemos realizar las consultas sobre la misma como si fuera una base de datos integrada de manera nativa por Android."

Comment: El ejemplo lo tienes, en la clase Pedido: `new ListSQLiteHelper(context, TABLE_NAME, NULL, 1);` Si lo ves, le pasa 4 parámetros. El problema es que estás iniciándote y te has querido saltar toda la base :) Lo lógico es primero aprender a trabajar con objetos, a crearlos, a llamar métodos... y luego ir subiendo. No se puede empezar a hacer una casa por el tejado! Simplemente añade los parámetros que te faltan en la llamada a tu `new Database(...)`, o quita los parámetros del constructor de la clase para que solo pida el `Context`.

Comment: @Benito-B Gracias por aclararme el error. Yo solo sigo la parte final cortita del tutorial. He modificado la pregunta para que sea más claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se puede, creando una instancia de la clase Database. No es necesario más que pasar el contexto en el constructor.

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
```

**Database.java**

```
package com.geologyapplications.minerals;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MINERALOGY.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public Cursor getMinerals() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MINERALOGY_ES", null);

        return cursor;

    }
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
        db = new Database(getActivity());
        cursor = db.getMinerals();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String nombreMineral = cursor.getString(0);
            textView.setText(nombreMineral);
        }
```